# Three-dimensional array arrives in wrong order at serial port

Tags: java, arrays, json, arduino, serial-port

For an university assignment I'm writing a java application that will run some game logic for an interactive LED table. The table itself is being controlled by either 2 Arduino Duemilanove or 1 Arduino Mega 2560.

To give the Arduino(s) information about which LEDs should be lit in which color I send the data over the serial port from a Raspberry Pi 3b+ to the Arduinos. As the table consists of 14 LED strips with 14 LEDs per LED strip and each LED has 3 color values (RGB) I store the data about the table in an int[14][14][3] array.

Before sending the array to the Arduino I create a JSON object of it (using the Jackson library) and then send the array as a String using jSerialComm. Depending on which Arduino setup I use I also either transfer the whole array to JSON or split it into two int[7][14][3] arrays before creating the JSON object.

As the data arrived in the wrong order at the serial port when I used 2 Arduinos and jSerialComm I now got a new Arduino Mega 2560 (as other SO questions suggested the wrong data order might occur due to an outdated PL2303 module) and tried it again with the same result. After some further research I now tried using JSSC instead of jSerialComm but still the same result shows up.

The java class that I use to send the data to the arduino looks like this (the outcommented code being the code where I used jSerialComm / 2 Arduinos):

```
package de.pimatrix.backend;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class SerialThread implements Runnable {

    public static SerialPort arduino1, arduino2;
    private int[][][] matrix = new int[14][14][3];

    private int[][][] matrixLeft = new int[7][14][3];
    private int[][][] matrixRight = new int[7][14][3];

    private Socket localHost;
    private Matrix matrixData;
    private ObjectInputStream in;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        SerialJSONWriter writer = new SerialJSONWriter();

        ServerSocket ss = null;
        localHost = null;
        matrixData = new Matrix(matrix);
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(62000); // erstellen eines lokalen Sockets auf Port 62000, um die zu übertragende
                                            // Matrix vom ClientThread
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                localHost = ss.accept();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            initializeInputStream();
            waitForMatrix();
            splitMatrix();

            try {
                writer.tryWrite(matrixRight, matrixLeft);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void splitMatrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
                if (i <= 6) {
                    matrixRight[i][j][0] = matrix[i][j][0];
                    matrixRight[i][j][1] = matrix[i][j][1];
                    matrixRight[i][j][2] = matrix[i][j][2];
                } else {
                    matrixLeft[i - 7][j][0] = matrix[i][j][0];
                    matrixLeft[i - 7][j][1] = matrix[i][j][1];
                    matrixLeft[i - 7][j][2] = matrix[i][j][2];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeInputStream() {
        try {
            InputStream input = localHost.getInputStream();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void waitForMatrix() {
        System.out.println("Waiting for Matrix");
        try {
            matrixData = (Matrix) in.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.matrix = matrixData.matrix;
    }

    class SerialJSONWriter implements AutoCloseable {

        // Zuweisen der seriellen Ports
//      private final SerialPort /*arduino1, arduino2,*/ arduinoMega;
        private jssc.SerialPort arduinoMega;

        public SerialJSONWriter() {
//          arduino1 = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM5");
//          arduino2 = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM6");
//          arduinoMega = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM7");
            arduinoMega = new jssc.SerialPort("COM7");
            try {
                arduinoMega.openPort();
                arduinoMega.setParams(115200, 8, 1, jssc.SerialPort.PARITY_EVEN);
            } catch (SerialPortException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//          arduinoMega.setBaudRate(115200);
//          arduinoMega.setNumDataBits(8);
//          arduinoMega.setNumStopBits(1);
//          arduinoMega.setParity(0);


            // setzen der Timeouts für die Kommunikation mit den Arduinos
//          arduino1.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_SCANNER, 0, 0);
//          arduino2.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_SCANNER, 0, 0);
//          arduinoMega.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_SCANNER, 0, 0);
//          arduino1.setBaudRate(115200);
//          arduino2.setBaudRate(115200);
//          arduinoMega.setBaudRate(115200);
//          arduino1.openPort();
//          arduino2.openPort();
//          arduinoMega.openPort();
//          arduino1.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING | SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0,
//                  0);
//          arduino2.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING | SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0,
//                  0);

//          arduinoMega.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING | SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0,
//                  0);
        }

        public void write() {

        }

        private void tryWrite(Object dataRight, Object dataLeft) throws IOException {
            String dataAsJSONRight = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dataRight) + "\n";
            String dataAsJSONLeft = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dataLeft) + "\n";
            try {
                arduinoMega.writeString(dataAsJSONRight);
            } catch (SerialPortException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//          for (int i = 0; i < dataAsJSONRight.length(); i++) {
////                arduino1.getOutputStream().write(dataAsJSONRight.getBytes()[i]);
//              System.out.println(dataAsJSONRight);
//              arduinoMega.getOutputStream().write(dataAsJSONRight.getBytes()[i]);
//          }
//          for (int i = 0; i < dataAsJSONLeft.length(); i++) {
////                arduino2.getOutputStream().write(dataAsJSONLeft.getBytes()[i]);
//              arduinoMega.getOutputStream().write(dataAsJSONLeft.getBytes()[i]);
//          }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception {
//          arduino1.closePort();
//          arduino2.closePort();
            arduinoMega.closePort();
        }
    }
}
```

On the Arduino(s) the processing looks like this:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PINROW0 2
#define PINROW1 3
#define PINROW2 4
#define PINROW3 5
#define PINROW4 6
#define PINROW5 7
#define PINROW6 8

#define NUMPIXELS 14 //Amount of pixels per row

Adafruit_NeoPixel row[] = { //Intitialize the array, that contains the addressable LED strips in the Adafruit format
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PINROW0, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PINROW1, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PINROW2, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PINROW3, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PINROW4, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PINROW5, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PINROW6, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800)
};

#define DELAY 1000 //set refresh cycle to 10 milliseconds
#define NUMSTRIPS 7/*(sizeof(row)/sizeof(row[0]))*/ //Amount of connected LED strips


int values[7][14][3];
int c = 0;
String matrixAsString = "";

void setup() {

  /*Setup serial port on which the Pi connects to the Arduino*/
  Serial.begin(115200); //set baudrate to 115200 Bit per second
  Serial.setTimeout(1000);

  Serial.println(100);

  /*initialize NeoPixel Library*/
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMSTRIPS; i++) {
    row[i].begin();
    row[i].show();
  }
}

void process(String matrixAsString) {
  StaticJsonDocument<4372> doc;
  Serial.println(matrixAsString);
  deserializeJson(doc, matrixAsString);

  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < 14; j++) {
      values[i][j][0] = values[i][j][1] = values[i][j][2] = (int) (doc[i][j][0]);
    }
  }
}

//infinite loop refreshing the matrix
void loop() {

  while (Serial.available()) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(matrixAsString);
    matrixAsString += c;
    if (c == '\n') {
      process(matrixAsString);
      matrixAsString = "";
    }

  }

}
```

When sending the data for a half matrix (so an int[7][14][3]):

> [[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[255,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]]

through the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE I get this output from the Arduino (as of the Serial.println() in `void loop`):

[image]

As one can see the first RGB values are transmitted correctly, however after even less than one complete LED strip the data arrives in the wrong order and (as you can see at the end of the picture) at some point completely stops showing up, which probably indicates no data is being read any more.

I've been trying a hell of things like changing the Arduino in case the PL2303 is outdated or defective as well as trying different libraries for serial communication however I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've spent over 30 hours trying different approaches to no avail so things are becoming really frustrating for me.

**UPDATE**

As suggested by [B.Letz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9972305/b-letz) I got the setup of the data, stop and parity bits right (now being 8 data, 1 stop and no parity bits). By reading the arduino feedback I still got the same results but after some tweeking I recognized that the problem probably was that my Serial.print apparently led to a massive lag on the Arduino so it couldn't handle all the data correctly and in time. After removing the first Serial.print call before doing the processing I now see the first matrix that is being transmitted being printed correctly by the Arduino. However for some reason for all further transmitted data the Arduino prints `null`. I'll try extending the timeouts in case the null pointer occurs due to a timeout on the Arduino-side.

**UPDATE 2**

Opposed to my assumption reconfiguring the timeouts didn't solve the problem. I also figured out that after the first JSON Object is sent the Arduino prints `null` to the console and only sends me the first JSON object after receiving the second JSON object. However this is the only time I get any feedback from the Arduino except `null`. What I also noticed is that when I send the JSON String over the serial monitor the Arduino instantly prints the correct String **BUT** it also prints an empty new line and doesn't respond to any new data in any kind.

Comment: Have you tried a slower baud rate? 115200 Baud is very fast for a serial connection and is only rated for ~1.2m (~4ft) of cable. Maybe try 19200 as baud rate and see if this helps at all.

Comment: @B.Letz Yes, I tried using different baud rates. Even when using 9600 Baud I didn't get appropriate results. If I remember correctly it even got worse as randomly a 0 turned to a 5 at some point of my test values.
I also tried setting the baud rates at server and arduino to different values (which I obviously didn't really expect to work though).

Comment: Is the JSON String correct or is that wrong too?

Comment: I analyzed my data at application level by printing it to Eclipse console and analyzed its structure by pasting and structuring it in a text editor and it indeed is a correct representation of the LED matrix. The sample of the int[7][14][3] I posted in the question is this exact data. Before sending the data it obviously is in the correct order. The wrong order appears as soon as logging it with the arduino and it doesn't matter if I transmit the String through the java application or the serial monitor of Arduino IDE.

Comment: On the Arduino it appears to me that you don't have set the 8 Data bits 1 Stop bit an EVEN Parity bit. Or am I overlooking that?

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I'll try it as soon as I get to work on the project later. However what might oppose this consideration is the fact that the first bytes of data are received correctly - if there was a wrong configuration with the data, stop and parity bits I would expect the data to be received incorrectly right from the beginning. I'd be very happy if I was mistaken at that point though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step for a working solution was removing the unnecessary `Serial.print()` call everytime a new char was read. After removing this line I could confirm the data arrived properly.
The shifted feedback as mentioned in my second update to the post:

> I also figured out that after the first JSON Object is sent the Arduino prints null to the console and only sends me the first JSON object after receiving the second JSON object. However this is the only time I get any feedback from the Arduino except null

occured due to the fact that I didn't wait long enough on the java application side for data to arrive before calling the `read()` function. After solving this I always received the correct string.

Trying out different configurations with either `DynamicJsonDocument` and `StaticJsonDocument` I now ended up using `DynamicJsonDocument` however also a `StaticJsonDocument` might have worked here.
A rather unpleasant issue was that in the inner for-loop in `void process` I accidently compared the counter variable to that of the outer for-loop, although I was able to retrieve the correct data at that point outside of the for-loop.

The problem asked in **this** questions is thereby solved, however a even bigger problem now occured as I'm not able to retrieve any data from the received JSON object as soon as I start implementing the code for controlling the LEDs and call `row[i].setPixelColor(j, row[i].Color(values[i][j][0], values[i][j][1], values[i][j][2]));` at any point in my code. So to sum things up this specific call is the actual reason that the code doesn't work properly.

**I'll be opening a new question for that new problem as it doesn't belong to this question thematically, however I will add a reference to it here, once it's written.**

---

**UPDATE**

The new question regarding addressing more than 7 LED strips using Adafruit's NeoPixel library can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370401/adafruit-neopixel-library-doesnt-work-when-addressing-more-than-7-led-strips).